# How to add additional attribute to an xml when using python

Tags: python, json, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml of the following format.
As we can see below, the new attribute that I want to add to the xml is the `location=""` to the `<status> tag`.

I am unsure on how to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Buildings>
        <FloorPlan id= "1.23">
            <InfoList>
                <state id = "0" val= "0" location=""/>              
            </InfoList>
                <OwnerA id = "1.87">
                <InfoList>
                     <status id = "1" val= "0" location=""/>
                </InfoList>             
               </OwnerA >           
        </FloorPlan>
</Buildings>
```

My code implementation is as of the following right now.

```
def add_attrib_to_xml():
    with open("xmlconfig.xml") as xmlConfigFile:
        xmlConfigFile = ET.parse(target)

    root = xmlConfigFile.getroot()

    location_attrib = ET.Element("location")  # Create `location` attribute to add 
    location_attrib.text = "No location"

    add_to_xml(root, location_attrib ) # TODO: yet to implement

def add_to_xml(root, location_attrib)
   # Not sure on how to do it
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks to all. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below - you just need to locate the element and add a new entry to the `attrib`  dict

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlstring = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Buildings>
        <FloorPlan id= "1.23">
            <InfoList>
                <state id = "0" val= "0" location=""/>              
            </InfoList>
                <OwnerA id = "1.87">
                <InfoList>
                     <status id = "1" val= "0" location=""/>
                </InfoList>             
               </OwnerA >           
        </FloorPlan>
</Buildings>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xmlstring)
status = root.find('.//status')
status.attrib['location'] = 'No location'
tree_as_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
print(tree_as_str)
```

output

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?>\n<Buildings>\n        <FloorPlan id="1.23">\n            <InfoList>\n                <state id="0" location="" val="0" />              \n            </InfoList>\n                <OwnerA id="1.87">\n                <InfoList>\n                     <status id="1" location="No location" val="0" />\n                </InfoList>             \n               </OwnerA>           \n        </FloorPlan>\n</Buildings>'
```

Comment: i converted it to a json string and I do not see the ```Location= No Location``` added to the nested nodes? Am I missing something here?

Comment: How did u convert the xml to json? Please share the code if you don't see the new attribute

Comment: To convert to json, I did this ```json_str = xmltodict.parse(ET.tostring(root, encoding="utf8"))```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for the method is as the following.

```
def add_to_xml(root)
    for el in root:
        if len(list(el)):    # check if element has child nodes
            status = root.find('.//status')
            status.attrib['Location'] = 'No Location'
            add_to_xml(el)
```

Adds the 'location' to the status node.